# Replace illegal filename characters with valid characters

Tags: c#, replace, character

I'm working on a video downloader and some of the titles have illegal characters in them. I have tried replacing the illegal characters with non illegal ones already, but it did not work. No matter what I do i keep getting this error: "The given path's format is not supported."

Here is my current code:

```
var videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(path, filename + video.VideoExtension));
            string invalid = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
            videoDownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Video " + args.ProgressPercentage + "% downloaded...");
            string invalidChars = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
        foreach (char c in invalidChars)
        {
            filename = filename.Replace(c.ToString(), "."); // or with "."
        }

        videoDownloader.Execute(); // where the error occurs.

        foreach (char c in invalidChars)
        {
            filename = filename.Replace(c.ToString(), "."); // or with "."
        }
```

I can easily fix this by adding custom filenames, but I would prefer to use the original filenames from the videos.

Also to note, I am using this library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/YoutubeExtractor

Comment: How does the video original name looks like? The one that gives you the error.

Answer (score 1):

You're handing `VideoDownloader` the old unfixed filename.  You need to replace bad characters before using the string, not after.